# Q;Determine date in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format

Tags: actionscript-3, date

I need to be able to subtract 2hrs ,8hrs, 1 day and 1 week from the current Date.

Then convert to yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

So far I have been unsuccessful.

What is the proper method to do this in actionscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options here, but I think the simplest solution in your case is to work with milliseconds. You can use += and -= to modify the current millisecond value of the date. The trickiest thing is the conversion of your values to milliseconds. Here are a few examples:

```
var myDate:Date; //assuming this is a actual date value.

//subtract 2 hrs
var twoHoursInMilliseconds:int = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000; //2 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds (in a second)
myDate.milliseconds -= twoHoursInMilliseconds;

//subtract 1 day
var oneDayInMilliseconds:int = 1 *24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
myDate.milliseconds -= oneDayInMilliseconds;
```

For formating, you will want to use this methods:

```
trace(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds());
```

Hopefully that points you in the right direction,

Happy Coding!

**Edit: Updated code to fix bug.**

Comment: Thanks Tyler.
I was wondering if I also need to modify the milliseoconds value to get local time. If I use Date.parse to get milliseconds I believe it returns UTCtime.

Comment: Another caveat Tyler, not possible to subtract milliseconds from a Date object as far as I know. What I did was convert first to milliseconds using the static valueOf method ie 'dateObject.valueOf()

Then create a new date and set the value of this new date object using the previously converted milliseconds value.

Comment: Oops that is a typo, it should have been: myDate.milliseconds -= oneDayInMilliseconds; Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with Tyler for his approach to work with date in the form of miliseconds.
For conversion, you may also like to use DateFormatter as below.

var dateFormatter:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
dateFormatter.formatString = 'yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' ;
var formattedDate:String = dateFormatter.format(d); 
trace(formattedDate);

Wishes,
Ashine.

Comment: I don't think their using Flex, but that would be the ideal formatting solution if they are!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the UTC values of the date/hour.

```
var d:Date = new Date();
d.dateUTC -= 1; //subtract one day
d.hoursUTC -= 1; //subtract one hour
```

and then trace the output using Tyler's trace statement.

```
trace(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds());
```

For more information on the Date class, check out http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/Date.html